# Donde puedo poner la lógica de negocio en Entity Framework usando repository pattern?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, .net-core, entity-framework-core

estoy usando Entity Framework con repository pattern pero me gustaría saber donde puedo poner mi lógica de negocio la cual es extensa.

Puedo crear una clase de nombre service y ahí poner mi lógica y desde ahí llamar el repositorio?

Ejemplo de mi proyecto.

Controller

```
private readonly IUserRepository _userRepository;
public UsersController(IUserRepository userRepository) {
    _userRepository = userRepository;
}

[HttpPost(Name = "PostUser"), AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<UserLoginResponseObject> Post(UserDto users)
{
    return await _userRepository.Create(users);
}
```

Interfaz

```
public interface IUserRepository
{
    Task<UserLoginResponseObject> Create(UserDto users);
    Task<List<UsersModel>> GetUsers();
    Task<ActionResult<UserLoginResponseObject>> GetOneUser(UserLoginDto user);
}
```

Repository

```
private readonly DataContextDb _db;
public UsersRepository(DataContextDb contextDb)
{
    _db = contextDb;
}

public async Task<UserLoginResponseObject> Create(UserDto users)
{
    BcryptService bcryptService = new();

    _db.Users.Add(new UsersModel {
        Id = users.Id,
        Name = users.Name,
        Age = users.Age,
        UserName = users.UserName,
        Password = bcryptService.HashPassword(users.Password)
        });

    await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
    return new UserLoginResponseObject { response = "Created" };
}
```

Comment: En la capa de negocios, algunos le llaman capa de aplicación. El Controller debería solo tener el request y pasarlo a la capa mencionada, y esa capa, se conecta con las interfaces del repositorio. Revisa sobre Arquitectura de Software.